# Unity2D - Enemies prefabs don't damage player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm doing a project where the player defeats enemies that appear infinitely. but when i create prefabs of an enemy, the prefabs can't read the references to the player's GameObjects.

I managed to make the prefabs follow the player by calling by GameObject in void start with

```
void Start(){ playerPosition = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform; }
```

but I couldn't reproduce that so the enemy can damage the player

```
void Start(){ playerBlood = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); }
```

I'm stuck on what to add after the `FindGameObjectWithTag("Player")`

Comment: Probably a [`.GetComponent<NameOfYourPlayerScript>();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) ...?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your player MonoBehaviour is called `Player` and your enemy script is called `Enemy` (changing the class names if not), an implementation along these lines might be of some use to you (allowing enemies to obtain a reference to the player object, and has a contrived example of how they can deal damage to the player object)

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Player: MonoBehaviour
{
  // ... pretend the rest of your code is here

  ///<summary>call this to hurt the player</summary>
  ///<param name="damageAmountIdk">amount of damage to deal or something</param>
  public void HurtMe(float damageAmountIdk)
  {
    // TODO: decrease the player's current health or something like that
  }
}
```

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour
{

    private Player _player;
    private Transform playerPosition;

    // ... rest of your code

    void Start()
    {
        _player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        playerPosition = _player.transform;
        //... other start method stuff
    }


    // demonstrating how the enemy can hurt the player
    void ContrivedMethodToDemonstrateHurtingThePlayer()
    {
        // this deals 42 damage to the player object.
        _player.HurtMe(42);
    }
}
```